# Why do I have to "Build-All" in Eclipse for my C++ program to run?

Tags: c++, eclipse

As the title states I have used Eclipse regularly in the past for making Java programs, it's been a simple process and when I click on the green run arrow the program compiles and then executes.

I've only ever written c++ in Netbeans and I've been asked to move over to Eclipse, I have everything set up but when I start a new program (c++ executable program) and it's never been run the first time I try to execute it with the green button I get the error `Launch Failed. Binary not found.`. If however I then go to project -> build all (or press Ctrl + B) it then allows me to run the program. Is there a reason for this? Can this behaviour be changed so that it acts like Java and just runs, or is this not possible?

Thankyou

Oh also if this matters I am on Windows 7 64bit running Eclipse Kepler 64bit with Cygwin 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Preferences->Launcing and enable the "Build (if required) before launching". And you probably want the "Save required dirty editors before launching" to "Always" as well.